# Fortran style formatting in R?

Tags: r, format

I have a list of different values, which I need to format in a specific way in a Fortran90 code.

The F90 file reads in the input file as the following format :

`'5E16.8'`

Meaning 5 columns, with scientific notation with a total column width of 16 and 8 decimal places.

A typical row of such an input file looks like this:

`-8.68914773E-03 -5.94151619E-03  2.34059840E-04 -2.76737270E-03 -4.90334584E-03`

Notice the negative signs take up an extra space for the total width, the length of the values is fixed on the amount of decimal places.

How would I go about formatting my strings and values from a list/matrix like this in R?

An example matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 0.5, 3.9, -40, 120))
```

Which, with the abovementioned format would look like:

```
  1.00000000E+00  2.00000000E+00  3.00000000E+00 -1.00000000E+00 -2.00000000E+00
 -3.00000000E+00  0.50000000E+00  3.90000000E+00 -4.00000000E+01  1.20000000E+02
```

Comment: Don't know, but have you read `?sprintf` really carefully yet ... ?

Comment: I have looked at cat/sprintf/write so far, but no luck. The issue is often with the negative sign being added as an extra char causing the spacing to mess up

Comment: `sprintf("%16.8e",m)` plus some `gsub()` work to convert `e+` to `E`?

Comment: (1) your third column has `E0` instead of `E00`, is that intentional? (2) what happens with numbers with magnitude <1 (i.e. negative exponents) ?

Comment: my example looks like it matches yours *except* for 0.5 (which is rendered as `5.00000...e-01` ...)

Comment: I forgot the + in the positive exponents, it's either a - for negative exponents and + for anything above 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to get pretty close:

```r
(ss <- toupper(sprintf("%16.8e",m)))
 [1] "  1.00000000E+00" "  2.00000000E+00" "  3.00000000E+00" " -1.00000000E+00"
 [5] " -2.00000000E+00" " -3.00000000E+00" "  5.00000000E-01" "  3.90000000E+00"
 [9] " -4.00000000E+01" "  1.20000000E+02"
```

Element 7 is different, `5.0...E-01` instead of `0.5...E+00`

Then convert to 5-column matrix:

```r
cat(apply(matrix(ss,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE),1,paste,collapse=""),sep="\n")
  1.00000000E+00  2.00000000E+00  3.00000000E+00 -1.00000000E+00 -2.00000000E+00
 -3.00000000E+00  5.00000000E-01  3.90000000E+00 -4.00000000E+01  1.20000000E+02
```

Comment: There is a difference here in how a value like `.1e-101` would be printed? In Fortran with `E16.8` we'd expect something like `0.10000000-100` which I suspect won't happen in this R without a little more effort.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure that `sprintf` is going to go down to C libraries for its definition, so it will be a C/Fortran (rather than R/Fortran) difference ... ?  I don't see anything in `sprintf` that looks helpful (thought `#` might do it but apparently not). The C/Fortran thing might be of interest to a broader audience (i.e. broader than R programmers ...)

Comment: Thanks for the help Ben, it works great :) My values go into max -10 neg exponent so I don't need to worry about that